# Create new instance of list or dictionary without class

Tags: python, python-3.3

How can I create a new instance of a list or dictionary every time a method is called? The closest thing I can compare what I would like to do is the `new` keyword in java or C#

Comment: `return []`? I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Are you having mutable default argument problems?

Answer (score 2):

These functions are **already defined**, there are **constructors** of built in types - dictionary and list:

```
x = dict()
y = list()
```

which is an equivalent of Java's

```
Map x = new TreeMap(); // or other dictionary implementation
List y = new ArrayList(); // or other list implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary example:

```
def create_dict():
    return {}
```

List example:

```
def create_list():
    return []
```

Usage:

```
a = create_dict() #for a new empty dictionary
b = create_list() # for new empty list
```

This all works but is not really that useful as it stands.

Comment: This is as close to what I want as I can get. Thanks.

Comment: Why not `return {}` in `create_dict()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a default list `L` and you want to make sure you're working with a list equal to `L` and not mutating `L` itself, you could initialize a local variable to `list(L)`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way (by far) is:

```
y= []    # new empty list
x= {}    # new empty dictionary
```

Why so short?  Because the language encourages the usage of high-level data structures like these.

In Python, constructors are invoked with the name of the class (like Java), but with no need for `new` or any other keyword.  As mentioned in another answer(s), this makes the following syntax also valid:

```
x= list()
y= dict()
```

However, you will rarely find them in practice.

List literals (like `[1,2,3,4]`) create new lists and pre-populate them.  Dictionary literals (like `{'Red':'Rojo','Yellow':'Amarillo','Green':'Verde'}`) create new dictionaries and pre-populate them too.

Set literals (like `{'Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night'}`) are also valid.  However, empty sets require to be created as `set()`.  The syntax `{}` is reserved to create empty dictionaries as they are more common.